# Error while creating an OS in cosmos

Tags: c#, operating-system, cosmos

I'm creating an OS in cosmos ( C# ) , but I cannot get the code right.
Here it is:

```
var input = Console.ReadLine();
if (input = 'h')
    Console.Write("This is the help section...");
else
    Console.Write("Invalid Command.");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

What I want it to do is that when I type in 'H' it should output the help section and when I type in something else, it should type in 'Invalid Command'.

It keeps saying 'Error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'char' to 'string'.

Full code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Sys = Cosmos.System;

namespace Dingo_OS
{
    public class Kernel : Sys.Kernel
    {
        protected override void BeforeRun()
        {
        Console.WriteLine("Thank you for trying out my OS. For any help, input /h.");
        }

        protected override void Run()
        {
            var input = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input = 'h')
                Console.Write("This is the help section...");
            else
                Console.Write("Invalid Command.");
            Console.WriteLine(input);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are writing an 'OS' and you are having problems with this code snippet? Perhaps try 'biting off' something a wee bit smaller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Console.ReadLine` returns a *string*, not a single character. So you need to compare it with a string. String literals uses double quotes, not single quotes. Also, you want the equality comparison operator (`==`) rather than the assignment operator (`=`):

```
if (input == "h")
```

To be honest, if you're sufficiently inexperienced in C# that this is causing you problems, I suggest you take a step back and learn the basics of C# in a more "normal" environment (e.g. console or client apps) first, before venturing into Cosmos. I haven't done any Cosmos work myself, but I *suspect* there will be some pretty tricky areas, which will be made *much* harder by not having a solid grounding in C# first.

Comment: Also, he is missing one equal sign. There is = instead of == in the if statement.

Comment: @OndrejJanacek: Yes, I'd edited it for that.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but is it a good practice to compare the string with == instead of .Equals???

Comment: @RahulTripathi: Yes, that's fine so long as both operands are strings at compile-time - the `==` operator is overloaded in C#.

Comment: Thanks! It works now, and yeah, you're right about the C# thing. Please let me know if you find any good tutorials.

Comment: @DanishHumair: I would suggest buying a good introductory book, to be honest. The latest edition of Head First C# is pretty good, C# in a Nutshell, or Effective C#.

Answer (score 0):

`Console.ReadLine` returns a `string` not a `char`, you can use `Console.ReadKey().KeyChar` for reading `char`

```
protected override void Run()
{
    var input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
    if (input == 'h')
        Console.Write("This is the help section...");
    else
        Console.Write("Invalid Command.");
    Console.WriteLine(input);
}
```